# Dired: move cursor to last position when entering a subdirectory again?

Tags: dired

When `dired` moves up a directory, in the new buffer, the cursor will be positioned on the directory from where it originated.

However, the other way around is not supported by default: upon returning to a subdirectory, the cursor will be placed on the first line of the `dired` list regardless of the file or directory that had been most recently visited in this subdirectory. This behaviour can be confusing when quickly switching between `dired` buffers.

Is it possible to make `dired` act in the intended way when entering a subdirectory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then you get the behavior you are looking for.

**`^`** takes you to the parent directory.  Hitting `RET` on the subdir line in that buffer takes you back to the subdir (Dired) buffer, and point is where you left it, there.

In addition, after it inserts a subdir listing, **`i`** flips back and forth between that listing and the subdir's line in the parent listing.